# Seed pgAdmin roles with Active Directory groups when using Docker

Tags: pgadmin

I want to setup a pgAdmin instance for our team using the Docker deployment. As our organization uses Active Directory, I'd like to assign the pgAdmin *User* role to a specific AD group when starting the pgAdmin Docker container.

Within the docs I already found the option to use pgAdmin with LDAP, so hopefully accessing our AD should work.

What I didn't find: is it possible to assign a pgAdmin role to an AD group or only to AD users? And if yes, can this automatically happen on Docker container start (e. g. by using an environment variable or a config file similar to `servers.json`)?

Or put in other words: is it possible that it looks like this after container start only by configuration without any manual interaction?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer from pgAdmin's support mailing list:

> pgAdmin does not have this option as of now. By default, users logged in with LDAP will have a 'User' role.
> You can track development on this in the issue - [#2483](https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/2483)

Since all the users I want to assign the 'User' role are members of the same AD group, it is sufficient for me to enable LDAP authentication and limit the LDAP search scope to the relevant AD group.